# Is it required to write init method in NSObject Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsobject

I'm writing a separate NSObject Class for my app, for WebService Calling, so i'm having a confusion that do i need to write init method explicitly like below,

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}
```

or even though if i ignore this and try to call from another class will it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need it you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Yep, its is auto-generated because your class extends NSObject

Comment: @Sune but if i didn't write it, & when i call a webService method defined in this class will it work since there is no init method, will class level initialization happens?

Comment: @GrahamBell you don't need to write it unless you want to initialize something inside it.

Comment: If you need class level initialization, you should put that in `init`. Are the other methods class methods or instance methods?

Comment: @Sune All of the methods are instance methods only

Comment: I think you may need to add a bit of the code, if you want a proper answer. The short answer is no, but there may be something specific in the implementation you use that makes it yes.

Comment: @FaddishWorm: It's not auto-generated. It's just implemented by the superclass (`NSObject`), so you inherit it automatically.

Comment: @SuneTrudslev: You only need to implement `-init` if the default behaviour is not enough. For instance, if you want to set your `favouriteVegetable` ivar to `@"potato"` in every new instance of your class, `NSObject` won't do that for you and you'll need to override.

Answer (score 4):

Like all methods in Objective C, the `init` method can be inherited. If you do not need to perform any initialization of the additional members of your class, you can use the `init` method of the superclass by omitting the method from your class.